# continuous Colormap over Surface Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, continuous

I'd like to create a continuous colormap with matplotlib on a 3D Surface Plot, where the color depends on the z-value of the surface. But with the "normal" plt functions the colormap fills the space between the gridpoints with the same color like shown in the picture. So there is no continuous change in color, rather there are just some colored surfaces stitched together:

```
x = range(0,126)
y = range(0,3)
#z is my data from the experiment

# make a grid of the x/y plane
X,Y= np.meshgrid(x,y)

# get the colormap for the graph
cmap=plt.get_cmap("RdBu")

# cmap = clr.LinearColormap.from_list('custom blue', ['#244162','#DCE6F1'], N=256)

#plot the corresponding z-value at every knot of the grid 
surface = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,z, cmap = cmap, antialiased=True, edgecolor='gray' , linewidth=0.2)

m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=surface.cmap,norm=surface.norm)
m.set_array(z)
plt.colorbar(m)

ax.set_yticks(y)
ax.set_xticks(x[::25])

plt.show()
```

which looks like this:
[3D-surface Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1kjH.png)

Do I need to interpolate the surface in between with more gridpoints, or is there a more elegant way? I'm a little lost in the documentation and syntax

Thanks in advance,
masterblibla

Comment: You only have three data points in y - it seems the chart is showing what you have?

Comment: Yes I only have the values at the gridpoints (3 in y direction), but I want the plane in between to get color coded based on its height in z direction.